# How to combine previously grouped rows by one or more shared rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database, I have two separate queries (q1, q2) joining across multiple tables assigning the same items to different groups (I call these subgroups) based on different criteria. I get query result 1 and 2 (qr1, qr2).

An item might appear in one or both, but within a result it is unique.
I want to assign a new group id based on both subgroups and assigning the same group id if the subgroups share one or more items.

```
qr1                           qr2
+----------+-------------+    +----------+-------------+
| item     | subgroup1    |   | item     | subgroup2   |
+----------+-------------+    +----------+-------------+
|       1  |           1 |    |        1 |           5 |
|       2  |           1 |    |        5 |           6 |
|       3  |           2 |    |        6 |           6 |
|       4  |           3 |    |        7 |           7 |
|       5  |           3 |    |        8 |           5 |
|       6  |           4 |    |       10 |           5 |
+----------+-------------+    +----------+-------------+
```

```
combined (interested in item and group):
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
| item    | subgroup1  | subgroup2  | group |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
|  1      | 1          | 5          | 1     |
|  2      | 1          | N          | 1     |
|  3      | 2          | N          | 2     |
|  4      | 3          | N          | 3     |
|  5      | 3          | 6          | 3     |
|  6      | 4          | 6          | 3     |
|  7      | N          | 7          | 4     |
|  8      | N          | 5          | 1     |
| 10      | N          | 5          | 1     |
+---------+------------+------------+-------+
```

- Subgroup 1 and 5 would be combined because of shared item 1. (group items 1, 2, 8, 10)
- Subgroup 3, 4! and 6 would be combined because of shared item 5. (group items 4, 5, 6)
- Subgroup 2 and 7 constitute their own group and do not share an item with any other group.

I tried to use window functions, count by duplicate item, and going from there. But I got stuck.

Comment: Subgroup 4 is not associated with item 5. It is associated with item 6 and since subgroup 6 is associated with both items 5 and 6, you want to include subgroup 4 with 3 and 6? It's included by indirect association? I very much doubt SQL alone can accomplish and 'easy way' will not describe the effort. When you have specific code with issue, post question.

Comment: The solution will likely involve recursive behavior.  See: `WITH RECURSIVE ...`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the request comments, you need a recursive query. The recursive part is what I call cte im my query. There is an array called items that I use to avoid cycles.

The idea is per item I assign all other items that are directly or indirectly associated the same group. Then I aggregate by item and take the smallest associated item and thus detect all items belonging to the same group. I use `DENSE_RANK` to get consecutive group numbers.

```
with recursive
  qr1(item, subgroup) as (values (1,1), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,3), (6,4)),
  qr2(item, subgroup) as (values (1,5), (5,6), (6,6), (7,7), (8,5), (10,5)),
  qr(item, subgroup) as (select * from qr1 union all select * from qr2),
  cte(item, other, items) as
  (
    select item, item, array[item]
    from qr
    union all
    select cte.item, g.item, cte.items || g.item
    from cte
    join qr on qr.item = cte.other
    join qr g on g.subgroup = qr.subgroup
    where g.item <> all (cte.items)
  )
select
  item, 
  min(qr1.subgroup) as sg1,
  min(qr2.subgroup) as sg2,
  dense_rank() over (order by min(other)) as grp
from cte
left join qr1 using (item)
left join qr2 using (item)
group by item
order by item;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/fG6AnX6l